# How do I Append files to a directory?

Tags: bash, unix

I need the move the output files from a command to a directory and use the output redirectors `>>` but it didn't work and shows this error.

`./ImportTest.sh: line 175: /opt/old/imptest-associate: Is a directory.`

Looks like the output redirection only works if it's text and redirecting to a file.

Can someone please guide me on how can I redirect OR append files to a directory.

Comment: You can't redirect the output of a command in that way, they use plain text, and you can't redirect it to a directory file. What exactly do you want to accomplish? If that command outputs files, then you have to modify that command directly to accept an output directory as an argument, if you can't, then you'll have to move those files manually with 'mv'

Answer (score 0):

Since your question does not clearly say what your command does, I assume your command outputs a list of file names and you want to move them to a directory.  Given that, why not move your files to the target directory?   With that in mind the following new script is one example of how to achieve it (this could be run in command line or awk or sed script as well.  I just haven't done it).

#!/bin/sh

#set of files to be appended.  This list of file names can instead be created by 
 #running your command that outputs files.

files='/users/foo/a /users/foo/b /users/foo/c /users/foo/d'

#your target directory in variable dir below where you want your files to move
 #to. This could be an argument to this script.

dir="/tmp/mydir"

for i in $files #loop through the files

do

```
    echo "file name is $i"#print file name

    #mv files to the directory. Note that I assume the list of file names is 
    #full path names

    mv $i $dir
```

done